# React Native Android APK Issue - Running fine on simulator

Tags: android, reactjs, react-redux, react-native

I am having an issue when building an Android APK file for react native.

The app is working fine on both Android and iOS simulators and also on physical iOS devices.

As it is a react native app the code is the same for both platforms.

The issue I am having is when I build the APK file for android, it builds and installs and launches fine however when I log into the app the Android app gets stuck at the login screen.

The app uses redux to handle redux calls and below is the following service used at login:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { config } from "../helpers/config";
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";

export const signinService = {
  loginService,
};

// Login
function loginService(details) {
  return axios({
    method: "post",
    url: `${config.apiUrl}/users/authenticate`,
    data: details,
  }).then((response) => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem(
      "user",
      JSON.stringify(response.data.userData)
    );
    AsyncStorage.setItem("responseData", JSON.stringify(response.data.responseData));
    AsyncStorage.setItem(
      "otherDataProperties",
      JSON.stringify(response.data.otherDataProperties)
    );
    AsyncStorage.setItem(
      "accountBalance",
      JSON.stringify(response.data.accountBalance)
    );
    return response;
  });
}
```

The Android software versions are;

- Android Gradle Plugin Version: 4.1.0
- Gradle Version: 6.5
- buildToolsVersion: 29.0.2
- minSdkVersion: 19
- Coded on a 2019 Macbook Pro
- APK tested on a range of android devices some of which include a pixel 3, Galexy S9 and galext S6

As mentioned the code running fine on both Android and iOS simulators and physical iOS devices.

Comment: Check `adb logcat` for error messages. Besides that you have to debug your app: https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging

Comment: Hi, @Robert unfortunately the log cat is showing no issues neither is Gradle help --warning-mode=all, debugging the app on the laptop is of no use as it is working as intended. Is there a way of debugging the app on the android phone itself?

Comment: Gradle is just for building the app, but your problems occur at run-time. The page I have linked in my first comment explains how to debug. Just read the page fully.

Comment: Hi @Robert, the log file is available here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14OA7mB2y79scewb1sqwlfFkIzPsMcSP6/view?usp=sharing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Log update - https://drive.google.com/file/d/14OA7mB2y79scewb1sqwlfFkIzPsMcSP6/view?usp=sharing